# Disable Form Field Unless

Tags: form, formatting

Within my SharePoint 2013 form I have a field labeled "Type of Outage" which has different six different choices.  Further down the form I have fields labeled "day of the week" and "week #".  These two fields are used in order for me to sort within views the way I need to.  I don't want users to be confused and think information needs to be placed here.

I would like to disable "day of the week" field at all times unless "type of outage" is equal to "telework".  I would like to do the same with "week #" if "type of outage" is equal to "AWS".

I did see this question asked recently but I feel like I am needing something a little different:

[Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198904/sharepoint-designer-hiding-fields-in-a-form-unless-specific-condition-is-met)

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: The question you're linking to, and its duplicate, both have correct answers to what you're trying to do. Pick one, try it, and if you get stuck *then* ask us for help.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid users confusion , I suggest instead of disabling / enable you can show and hide theses fields on demand based on your choice field selected value via Jquery by doing the following :

- Open your new form via the browser.
- Edit Page .

[image]

- Add web Part > Add Script Editor .

[image]

Add the following code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
//Show/hide columns based on Choice Field Selection
$("select[title='Type of Outage']").change(function() {
if ($("select[title='Type of Outage']").val() != "telework")
{
$('nobr:contains("day of the week")').closest('tr').hide();
}
else
{
$('nobr:contains("day of the week")').closest('tr').show();
}
});
});

</script>
```

For step by step guide with images [check Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection using JQuery in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thanks for the assistance but this is not working for me.  The field stays no matter the choice.

Comment: Dear @FlatBanana first make sure that you provide the correct field name , the second Are  you tried to change the value in the choice field after you add this code ? third are you need to hide it once the form opened ? the last thing is it the default SharePoint form. I am pretty sure the above code is working where I wrote the attached article and I mentioned all details with screenshot , so please try to make sure you do the mentioned instructions , also don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification